# Image of a basis of a free module is a basis of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose $M$ is a free module over a commutative ring $A$ with unity. Let $N=\mathscr m M$, where $\mathscr m$ is a maximal ideal of $A$. How do I show that the image of any $A$-basis $\{m_i|i=1,\dots,s\}$ for $M$ is an $A$-module is a basis for $M/N$ as an $A/\mathscr m$-vector space?

I think can see that the image of a particular basis (the standard basis) of $M=A^n$ is the standard basis of $M/N$. I can also see that the image of a generating set is a generating set of $M/N$ as an $A/\mathscr m$-vector space. But I don't see how to prove independence of the image of an arbitrary basis.

Suppose $(a_1+\mathscr m)(m_1+N)+\dots(a_s+\mathscr m)(m_s+N)=0+N$ is $M/N$. Taking the preimage under the quotient map, we get $a_1m_1+\dots+a_sm_s\in N$, but I don't see how to use linear independence of $m_1,\dots,m_s$ over $A$ to conclude that all $a_i+\mathscr m$ are zero.

Comment: All those $(a_i + A)$'s should be $(a_i + I)$'s, yes? Also $I = m$?

Comment: Right, fixed, thanks.

Comment: Oh one more, $M = A^n$, not $R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

You're just given that $M$ is a free module. There is no "standard basis" for $M$, right off the bat. The choice of any basis induces an isomorphism $M \cong A^n$ sending that basis to the standard basis of $A^n$. Then your argument for $A^n$ carries forward.